# Map Network Drive (Firestick) to Windows7 using ip address of firestick

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm trying to do this so media app VLC on the firestick can see my shared folder but I'm not sure I have the correct syntax. I tried using 
`\\192.168.x.xx` in the "Map Network Drive" window, but Windows says it can't find it. If I ping it from cmd window I get 4 replies.

Here is background info -

I am actually streaming from my PC to the firestick as I type this. It shows that ip address in my firewall connections window! To explain this is quite long because this is a tinywall firewall bug, if you can call it that. Years ago I made 3 shareable folders after I uninstalled tinywall, then reinstalled it. Now it keeps those shared folders just fine, but it locks down making new ones, but the author says if I map a network drive, the firewall will pass it just fine. Thing is I don't know the syntax for the firestick UNC name, but I do know the ip address, so that's what I'm trying to solve here. I can't browse my network because the tinywall firewall has locked that off, but that's ok if I can get the proper name of the firestick or the proper ip address syntax.

Comment: Does you can "open" your device by IP in Explorer window and view its shared resource names?

Comment: No, I can't but this is the strange thing. I am actually streaming from my PC to the firestick as I type this. It shows that ip address in my firewall connections window!